# K-means in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have a Knowledge Base (KB) represented by a Matrix A=(100x15) and I have to clustering this KB into 5 cluster.

I used the code in Matlab:

```
idx=kmeans(A,5)
```

I obtained a result idx with the index of cluster for each row of matrix A.

Now I have a new vector B=(1x15) a sort of new entry and I have to clustering this new vector starting from the previous clustering obtained.

When I add the new entry B to the KB and I recall the function with C (composed by A and B)

```
idx1=kmeans(C,5)
```

I obtain a new idx1 with all results different from idx.

My scope is understand the cluster of B with respect to the cluster obtained clustering the KB.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what are you asking? Are you asking why the clusters change?

Comment: Dear Dan,
I know why the cluster change, I would like to know, how to fix the cluster in order to clustering future entry starting from the KB cluster.

Comment: `idx` already tells you that

Comment: ok thanks, but now i have another vector (in addition to KB) of which I have to know the cluster , basing the previous cluster obtained with the KB.

Comment: If you don't want the clusters to change, then `idx` still holds even after you add your extra feature

Comment: how I can do to fix idx?

Comment: Your question is not clear. `idx` is a vector of which observation fall into which clusters. If you want to add a feature and keep the clusters the same then `idx` is still a vector of your clusters. You don't need to do anything! How were you planning on proceeding once you found your clusters?

Comment: At the beginning with KB idx is 

idx=[2 3 4 1 3 2 4 ........]'. when I add a new entry and I recall kmeans the idx become: idx=[ 3 2 1 3 4 2 ....]'. The idx change (I know why). My question is: How can I obtain the cluster of each new vector starting from the cluster obtained from the KB?

Comment: @user3043636: do you want to (a) map the indices of one kmeans onto the indices of another round of clustering, so that cluster idx 1 refers to the same cluster both times, or (b) given clusters from the KB, find out to which cluster each entry from B belongs?

Comment: Dear Jonas, thanks for your help, the answer is (b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to compare the new data point to the already-identified clusters. I'm not sure this will *always* give the results you expect, but you could just compute Euclidean distances to each cluster *centroid* and pick the smallest.

**Example**

Original data, constructed so as to have four clusters:

```
%// original data
A=[randn(25,1),   randn(25,1);
   randn(25,1)+5, randn(25,1);
   randn(25,1)+5, randn(25,1)+5;
   randn(25,1),   randn(25,1)+5];
plot(A(:,1),A(:,2),'k.');
hold on;
```

[image: 100 random points]

K-means clustering with K=4 clusters:

```
K=4;
[idx,centroids]=kmeans(A,K);
for n=1:K
    plot(A(idx==n,1),A(idx==n,2),'o');
end
```

[image: Original points clustered]

Note that the second output of `kmeans` returns the centroid coordinates for each cluster.

Random new point:

```
%// new point:
B=2*randn(1,2);
plot(B(1),B(2),'rx');
```

Distance between new point and all centroids:

```
dist2cent = sqrt(sum((repmat(B,[K,1])-centroids).^2,2));
```

Index of smallest distance:

```
[~,closest] = min(dist2cent);

plot([centroids(closest,1), B(1)],...
     [centroids(closest,2), B(2)],...
     'r-');
```

[image: Random new point clustered by closest centroid]

Comment: Dear Geoff, thanks for your proposal, I think that could be very useful for my problem. 
But the main problem is understand the number cluster of point B starting from the clusters associated to Matrix A. We can Imagine to have Matrix A as a static matrix where after the Matlab function [idx centroids]=kmeans(A,4) we know the idx that should be the number of cluster for each row entry of A, Now I have a new vector B I have to know the cluster of B knowing idx e centroids, if idx=[1 3 2 1 4 1] of A the result with B should be idx1=[1 3 2 1 4 1 3] with '3' cluster of B. How can i do?

Comment: If I understand correctly, my solution provides you the information you're looking for. The variable `closest` is the cluster number of the new vector `B`. In other words if `idx = [1 3 2 1 4 1]` then `idx1=[1 3 2 1 4 1 closest]`.

Comment: Absolutely Great.
I take this opportunity to make another question. Obtained the clusters of A and the cluster of B based on A, now for each time that i compile the program (or code, in a few words each time that I launch the function kmeans(.....) ) with A and B fixed (hence no random numbers) how can I obtain always the same cluster index (basically the vector idx have to remains always the same).? Thanks in advance